# Video player for macOS with persistent playback speed setting

Tags: macos, quicktime

I regularly watch videos at 1.7x and would like for that **preference** to be saved across different videos instead of needing to manually reset it each time.

Is there such a setting for QuickTime for macOS? Alternatively, any other player capable for playing MP4 files with such option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[VLC for macOS](https://www.videolan.org) is the video player you are looking for. It includes support for wide variety of audio and video codecs. Get the latest version from the [download page](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) or install via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) by running:

`brew cask install vlc`

Once installed, open VLC Preferences by going to VLC → Preferences in the Menu bar or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. Click **Show All** button in the bottom left corner of the preferences window, click on **Input/Codecs** item in the left sidebar, and set the desired value for **Playback speed**. Once entered, click on the **Save** button in the bottom right to finalize your changes.

[image]

The playback speed will now persist for any subsequent media file that you will play.

Alternatively, if you do not wish to have a persistent speed setting, and wish to tweak it while a audio/video file is playing, do so in realtime via Playback → Playback Speed VLC Menu bar item.

[image]

Comment: Even after installing `vlc` I would *never* have found that setting without your detailed dialog screenshots. *Thank you*.

Comment: hmm.. after setting to 1.75X and opening an `.mp4` it is running at regular 1.X speed. I re-opened the dialog and it *does* show 1.75x. This is strange.

Comment: @javadba Make sure to save the changes made in preferences by hitting the Save button in the bottom right.

Comment: ya - i had done that - and had exited and re-entered the settings dialog to ensure the update had "taken".  I'm quitting the app/restarting now to try that

Comment: I see the problem: it is that `Finder` - `Open with | VLC.app` does *NOT* work: it opens with `QuickTime` instead! Try it out!

Comment: @javadba Most likely some other issue. It appears to work fine for me. (macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, VLC 3.0.4).

Comment: Found out the reason: this is a *work* computer and they have disallowed "Open Apps from Unidentified Developer".  I will need to use the `VLC`-specific `Open File` dialog instead of `Finder.

Comment: Unrelated: I really appreciate your very helpful edits!